# Outlier detection in multiple columns using quantile returns an error

Tags: python, quantile

I want to keep outlier in two columns with values above and below quartiles. The dataframe itself has 10 columns. Below is my code. But the last line of the codes returns a `KeyError: 0.99`.

```
outliers_cols = df[['ColA', 'ColB']]

low = 0.01
high = 0.99
qtldf = outliers_cols.quantile([low, high])

outliers_df = df[(outliers_cols > qtldf[high]) | (outliers_cols < qtldf[low])]
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to index improperly into the `qtldf` dataframe. Use `loc` instead :

```
qtldf.loc[high]
```